# Cscore play state change event

Tags: c#, cscore

I'm making simple audio player with c# using the [cscore](https://cscore.codeplex.com/) library.
However, because of lack of documentation I'm not able to find documentation for play state change event. Can you give me example?
I need something like this example in WmpLib:

```
player.PlayStateChange += new WMPLib
    ._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(player_PlayStateChange);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [stopped](http://filoe.github.io/cscore/sharpDox/1.1.0-release/#type/ISoundOut?Stopped) event. 
But no event for playing or paused playbackstate.